# Insert only 3 fields into mysql table of 54 fields

Tags: mysql

How to insert data in only 3 fields of a  MySQL database table having 54 fields

regards

Comment: name the fields in your insert statement

Comment: If you are using OO language. I suggest using bolb datatype and save the object instead of having `51 fields null` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the columns like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tableName` ( `col1`, `col2`, `col3` ) 
VALUES ( 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' );
```

That way, just the listed columns will receive values through the query. All other columns will be set to their respective default value (or null).

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. specify the column definition first and then with its corresponding values.

But be sure that the remaining columns accepts `NULL` or it must be specified with `default` value.

[Document](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

```
INSERT INTO tbl(col1, col2, col3) VALUES("VALUE","VALUE","VALUE")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO database (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
```

ignore the rest of the fields

Answer (score 0):

use this:

Assume

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,...fieldN )
                       VALUES
                       ( value1, value2,...valueN );
```

For Your case

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,field3)
                       VALUES
                       ( value1, value2,value3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into tablename ('column1','column2','column3')
values('val1','val2','val3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify field you need in INSERT statement, e.g. -

```
INSERT INTO table1(column1, column2, column3) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
```

**Note:** all other columns MUST have default values -

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  column1 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  column2 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  column3 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  column4 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'default value for column4',
  column5 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'default value for column5'
)
```